# Shorten jQuery animation loader

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

I have tried to do animation with squares in Jquery and it works good, but I want to know, if is it possible to write this script in shorter version and how to do it shorter.

Can someone tell me what to do for shorter version?

Or can someone to do it and then explain it?

I have tried to inser code here, but this code its realy long and stackoverflow sent me tip "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Link in comment

Thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/soorta/pen/NWbYJby

Comment: try using for loop

Comment: and can you show me example?